# AWS EBS Optimised Instance on load test showing only Instance Throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ebs

Can someone help m e to understand with how the throughput works with EBS Optimised Instance. I am in process of benchmarking EBS disk for MSSQL server on top of EC2 instances. Today i did perform a IOPS test using CrystalDiskMark tool and i found that when with perfmon counters the maximum throughput its showing is the one assigned to the instance , as an example I am using X1e.4XLarge which is having a throughput of ~230 MiB/s and during test i am getting this number only , so just wanted to understand why i am not getting EBS throughput as what it supposed to provide , reason being per aws documentation with EBS optimized instances we get dedicated network between ec2 instances and ebs volumes and instance throughput is additional on top of EBS throughput..

```
Is that something wrong i am performing or seeing data stats with benchmarking. Highly appreciate help.
```

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault not here. But more important, what throughput number do you expect, and why? When I look at the specs for x1e.4xl, 230 MB/sec seems about right.

Comment: Thats correct and that is instance throughput which is additional in nature . Lets say if i attach EBS volume so i am not seeing EBS volume throughput over there which is strange.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to convey. However, my original advice stands: post this question on ServerFault, and _show your tests_. Put the actual numbers in the question, and compare them to the numbers that you expect to see.